# "What's to discuss?" vs. "what's there to discuss?"

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning between *what's to discuss?* and *what's there to discuss?* For example:

> **What's to discuss?**/**what's there to discuss?** Everything is decided. I'm not going to sell the house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning. There is, however, a difference in formality. They are both utilized by people with authority when speaking to a subordinate, but the situation's level of formality and the attitude of the speaker will dictate which one should be used. "What's to discuss" is much less formal than "What's there to discuss", but can be harsher. So, since they can be used interchangeably, it is up to you to decide which one you wish to use.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Thanks for writing some very good answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference in meaning.